# Grouping 15 people into 5 groups

Tags: combinatorics

I want to ask if I want to group 15 different people into 5 groups; and with A and B must be in a group how many number of ways that allow me to do that.
My thought is that we knew that 2 people must be in a group so we would have$$\frac{13C1*12C3*9C3*6C3*3C3}{5!}$$
However, the answer turns out to be that:$$\frac{13C1*12C3*9C3*6C3*3C3}{4!}$$
May I know why？ Because I thought that there would be 5 identical groups so we need to use 5! to cancel the repetition. Thank you so much.

Comment: Try a simpler question: grouping $4$ different people into $2$ groups of two with A and B in the same group.  The correct answer is $\frac{2C0 * 2C2}{1!}=1$ rather than $\frac{2C0 * 2C2}{2!}=0.5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group with A and B is in a sense special and you chose it first.  The other four are not and so their different orders duplicate.

Perhaps it might be clearer as $$13C1*\dfrac{12C3*9C3*6C3*3C3}{4!}$$ or even as  $13C1*\frac{1}{4!}\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}$

Comment: To add to Henry's answer, the group with $A$ and $B$ is distinguished by containing $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I thought that we have 5 groups after choosing, and the A and B could be placed in any of the 5 groups; so we still need to divide by 5!.

Comment: @HenryCai - In that case you also need to consider choosing A and B in the second group, or the third or fourth or fifth, rather than just the first.  This will multiply the answer by $5$ and you can then divide this larger number by $5$ to get back to the same number.

Comment: This clears my doubt, thank you.